# Apply function to all Eigen matrix element

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have an `Eigen::MatrixXd` and I would like to modify all its elements by applying a function component-wise. For example:

```
MatrixXd m = ...;

for each m[i][j]:
  m[i][j] = exp(m[i][j]);
```

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, use the [`Eigen::MatrixBase<>::unaryExpr()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7) member function. Example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Core>

double Exp(double x) // the functor we want to apply
{
    return std::exp(x);
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m << 0, 1, 2, 3;
    std::cout << m << std::endl << "becomes: ";
    std::cout << std::endl << m.unaryExpr(&Exp) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @XingShi No, because [`std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp) has overloads, and `unaryExpr` is unable to deduce the functor signature from `std::exp` alone (i.e., there are more than 1 candidates). If you "help" the compiler by specifying the functor type, like `m.unaryExpr<double(*)(double)>(&std::exp)`, it will work.

Comment: According to the API reference std::ptr_func must be used to convert a pointer to a function in a functor, which is what is passed as argument to unaryExpr.
m.unaryExp( std::ptr_func(&Exp) );

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the comment. However it's not a must, the API says that *`std::ptr_fun` can be used...*, see e.g. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#title108 In this case, the function name decays to a pointer automatically by the rules of C++, and a function pointer behaves like a functor. Moreover, `std::ptr_fun` is deprecated in C++11, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ptr_fun.

Comment: Does anyone knows how I can assign the matrix returned from `m.unaryExpr(&Expr)` to a new object?

Answer (score 29):

[vsoftco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33786772/2899559)'s answer is very general and is good for custom functions. However, there is a simpler way for many of the commonly used functions. Adapting his example we can use `array`s and it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m << 0, 1, 2, 3;
    std::cout << m << "\nbecomes:\n";
    std::cout << m.array().exp() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is also of note as it would appear that this approach results in more efficient (read vectorised) machine code https://godbolt.org/z/YE_RJr

Comment: For future users who want to know what other coefficient-wise functions Eigen supports, see here: [Catalog of Eigen coefficient-wise math functions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html)

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, in C++11 and beyond, this also works with lambda functions.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Core>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m << 0, 1, 2, 3;
    std::cout << m << std::endl << " ->  " 
    std::cout << m.unaryExpr([](double x){return x + 1}) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@vsoftco's answer got me 99% of the way on this problem, but for some reason passing `&Exp` to `.unaryExpr()` was giving me compilation errors (g++, c+11, Eigen 3.3.5 gave error relating to:  `base type ‘double (*)(double)’ fails to be a struct or class type`).

However, I found that creating a `std::function` object and passing that instead fixed this. Copying @vsoftco's example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Core>

double Exp(double x) 
{
    return std::exp(x);
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd m(2, 2);
    m << 0, 1, 2, 3;
    std::function<double(double)> exp_wrap = Exp; //added to @vsoftco's answer
    std::cout << m << std::endl << "becomes: ";
    std::cout << std::endl << m.unaryExpr(exp_wrap) << std::endl; //and used here
}
```

I'm not sure how much overhead using a `std::function` object (or `std::ptr_fun`) gives compared to passing `&Exp`, but I couldn't get it to work without these alternatives.

Cheers