# Unknown errors within the C++ Eigen library for setting vectors/matrices

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, eigen

I am trying to implement the Longstaff and Scwartz algorithm that essentially is a Least-Squares method to price American options. I am using Matlab code as a reference to program this in C++.

What I have done thus far is first I set a time step variable named

`dt = T/N` where `T` is the expiration time, and `N` is the number of time steps.

Then a time vector (in Matlab denoted `t = 0:dt:T`). I created a function for this in C++ that is posted below:

```
    VectorXd range(double min, double max, int N){
    VectorXd m(N + 1);
     double delta = (max-min)/N;
     for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
             m(i) = min + i*delta;
     }
    return m;
}
```

Then I have to generate a vector that generates a set of normally distributed random numbers. In Matlab the function is called `z = randn(M/2,1)` where `M` is the number of paths. In C++ I made a function for this which is listed below:

```
MatrixXd generateGaussianNoise(int n, int m){
    MatrixXd M(n,m);
    VectorXd V(n);
    normal_distribution<double> nd(0.0, 1.0);
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            M(i,j) = nd(gen);
        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

Now we have to create another vector called `w = (r-sigma^2/2)*T + sigma*sqrt(T)*[z;z]`. Before this I had to create another C++ function for handling the Matlab syntax `[z;z]` This is listed below:

```
MatrixXd generateMatrix(MatrixXd z){
    MatrixXd Dm(2*z.rows(),z.cols());
        Dm << z, -z;
        return Dm;
}
```

Then I can create the `w` variable with another C++ function I created listed below:

```
MatrixXd generateWMatrix(double r, double sigma, double T, MatrixXd Dm){
    MatrixXd w(Dm.rows(),Dm.cols());
    for(int i = 0; i < Dm.rows(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Dm.cols(); j++){
            w(i,j) = (r - pow(sigma,2)/2)*T + sigma*sqrt(T)*Dm(i,j);
        }
    }
        return w;
}
```

Now we have to create a new variable `S = S0*exp(w)` where `S0` is the initial asset price. We can do this in a for loop which is listed below:

```
MatrixXd S(w.rows(),w.cols());
        for(int i = 0; i < w.rows(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < w.cols(); j++){
                S(i,j) = exp(w(i,j));
            }
        }
```

Now this is where things for me get a bit ugly which is the **Main Point** of this post. We have to do a backward for loop for the actual algorithm. I will present the beginning part of the Matlab code for reference which is where things go wrong for me in C++:

```
for i = N:-1:2

    z = randn(M/2,1);
    w = t(i)*w/(t(i+1)) + sigma*sqrt(dt*t(i)/(t(i+1)))*[z;z];
```

Now in C++ what I try to do is this:

```
for(int i = N; i >= 2; i--){
      z(i) = generateGaussianNoise(M/2, 1);
      zz(i) = generateMatrix(z);
      w(i) = t(i)*w(i)/(t(i+1)) + sigma*sqrt(dt*t(i)/(t(i+1)))*zz(i);
}
```

Although I get the following errors for `z(i)`:

```
cannot convert 'Eigen::MatrixXd {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>}' to 

'Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1>::Scalar {aka 
double}' in assignment
```

and for `zz(i)` I get the following error:

```
cannot convert 'Eigen::MatrixXd {aka Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>}' to 

'Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, 1>::Scalar {aka double}' in assignment
```

and for `w(i)` I get the following error:

```
invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
double sqrt(double)
float sqrt(float)
long double sqrt(long double)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type sqrt(#0)
const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sqrt_op<#0::Scalar>,const #0> sqrt(const Eigen::ArrayBase<#0> &)
float sqrt(float)
long double sqrt(long double)
std::complex<#0> sqrt(const std::complex<#0> &)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the latter above or what these errors mean. Of course I have tried googling them to see what the problem is but I don't get any useful information. For completeness I will post my whole code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
#include <random>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;


double LaguerreExplicit(int R, double x); // Generates the (weighted) laguerre value
double payoff_Call(double S, double K); // Pay off of a call option
MatrixXd generateGaussianNoise(int n, int m); // Generates Normally distributed random numbers
double LSM(double T, double r, double sigma, double K, double S0, int N, int M, int R);
// T        Expiration time
// r        Riskless interest rate
// sigma    Volatility
// K        Strike price
// S0       Initial asset price
// N        Number of time steps
// M        Number of paths
// R        Number of basis functions

VectorXd range(double min, double max, int N);
MatrixXd generateMatrix(MatrixXd z);
MatrixXd generateWMatrix(double r, double sigma, double T, MatrixXd z);

int main(){
double r = 0.06;
double sigma = 0.25;
int T = 1.0;
int N = 2;
double dt = T/N;
    VectorXd t = range(0.0, T, N);

    MatrixXd result1 = generateGaussianNoise(2,1);


    MatrixXd result2 = generateMatrix(result1);

    MatrixXd w = generateWMatrix(r,sigma,T, result2);







}


double payoff_Call(double S, double K){
    double payoff;
    if((S - K) > 0)
    {
        payoff = S - K;
    }else
    {
        payoff = 0.0;
    }
    return payoff;
}

double LaguerreExplicit(int R, double x){
    double value;
    if(R==0)
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    else if(R==1)
    {
        value = 0.5*(pow(x,2) - 4.0*x + 2);
    }
    else if(R==3)
    {
        value = (1.0/6.0)*(-1*pow(x,3) + 9*pow(x,2) - 18*x + 6);
    }
    else if(R==4)
    {
        value = (1.0/24.0)*(pow(x,4) - 16*pow(x,3) + 72*pow(x,2) - 96*x + 24);
    }
    else if(R==5)
    {
        value = (1.0/120.0)*(-1*pow(x,5) + 25*pow(x,4) - 200*pow(x,3) + 600*pow(x,2) - 600*x + 120);
    }
    else if (R==6)
    {
        value = (1.0/720.0)*(pow(x,6) - 36*pow(x,5) + 450*pow(x,4) - 2400*pow(x,3) + 5400*pow(x,2) - 4320*x + 720);
    }
    else{
        cout << "Error!, R is out of range" << endl;
        value  = 0;
    }
    value = exp(-0.5*x)*value; // Weighted used in Longstaff-Scwartz
    return value;
}

MatrixXd generateGaussianNoise(int n, int m){
    MatrixXd M(n,m);
    normal_distribution<double> nd(0.0, 1.0);
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            M(i,j) = nd(gen);
        }
    }
    return M;
}

VectorXd range(double min, double max, int N){
    VectorXd m(N + 1);
     double delta = (max-min)/N;
     for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
             m(i) = min + i*delta;
     }
    return m;
}

MatrixXd generateMatrix(MatrixXd z){
    MatrixXd Dm(2*z.rows(),z.cols());
        Dm << z, -z;
        return Dm;
}


MatrixXd generateWMatrix(double r, double sigma, double T, MatrixXd Dm){
    MatrixXd w(Dm.rows(),Dm.cols());
    for(int i = 0; i < Dm.rows(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Dm.cols(); j++){
            w(i,j) = (r - pow(sigma,2)/2)*T + sigma*sqrt(T)*Dm(i,j);
        }
    }
        return w;
}



double LSM(double T, double r, double sigma, double K, double S0, int N, int M, int R){
    double dt = T/N;
    VectorXd t = range(0,T,N);
    MatrixXd z = generateGaussianNoise(M/2, 1);
    MatrixXd zz = generateMatrix(z); // Need to do this for the [z;-z]
    MatrixXd w = generateWMatrix(r, sigma, T, zz);
    MatrixXd S(w.rows(),w.cols());
        for(int i = 0; i < w.rows(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < w.cols(); j++){
                S(i,j) = exp(w(i,j));
            }
        }
    MatrixXd P(S.rows(), S.cols());

    MatrixXd z_new(M,1);
    for(int i = N; i >= 2; i--){
        z_new.topRows(M/2) = generateGaussianNoise(M/2,1);
        z_new.bottomRows(M/2) = -z_new.topRows(M/2);
        w = t(i-1)*w/t(i) + sigma*sqrt((dt*t(i-1)/t(i)))*z_new;
    }







    return 0;

}
```

**Update:**
I added the new full code but I am still getting some errors in the `exp()` and `sqrt()` in the function called `double LSM(double T, double r, double sigma, double K, double S0, int N, int M, int R)` I have tried to google what I could but I don't have any idea how to fix the following error messages:

For `exp()` I get this message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
double exp(double)
float exp(float)
long double exp(long double)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type exp(#0)
const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_exp_op<#0::Scalar>,const #0> exp(const Eigen::ArrayBase<#0> &)
float exp(float)
long double exp(long double)
std::complex<#0> exp(const std::complex<#0> &)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type
```

For the `sqrt()` I get this message:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
double sqrt(double)
float sqrt(float)
long double sqrt(long double)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type sqrt(#0)
const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sqrt_op<#0::Scalar>,const #0> sqrt(const Eigen::ArrayBase<#0> &)
float sqrt(float)
long double sqrt(long double)
std::complex<#0> sqrt(const std::complex<#0> &)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type
```

Here is the Matlab code I am trying to implement in Eigen. I will just post the parts in the Matlab code that I have done successfully and the parts that I having a hard time implementing:

```
function u = LSM(T,r,sigma,K,S0,N,M,k)
% T Expiration time
% r Riskless interest rate
% sigma Volatility
% K Strike price
% S0 Initial asset price
% N Number of time steps
% M Number of paths
% k Number of basis functions
dt = T/N; % Time steps
t = 0:dt:T; % Time vector
z = randn(M/2,1);
w = (r-sigmaˆ2/2)*T + sigma*sqrt(T)*[z;-z];
S = S0*exp(w);
P = max(K-S,0); % Payoff at time T
for i = N:-1:2
z = randn(M/2,1);
w = t(i)*w/t(i+1) + sigma*sqrt(dt*t(i)/t(i+1))*[z;-z];
```

Everything after the for loop is where I am struggling...

Comment: Could you provide some pseudo (or Matlab) code of what you actually intend to do? Ideally, reduce it to the parts you don't understand how to implement with Eigen.

Comment: @chtz Yes, I will do that now

Comment: `dt = T/N; t = 0:dt:T;` is unsafe, if `dt` is rounded up. You should use `t=linspace(0,T,N+1)` instead. Also, use its Eigen equivalent `VectorXd::LinSpaced(size,low,high)`

Comment: Does linspace create a uniform sequence of numbers? As in if dT = 1/2 and we t = 0:1/2:1, then the output would be 0 1/2 1

Comment: Please do not edit your question to ask entirely new questions!

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please don't edit your posts to ask new questions that completely invalidate the present answers. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @BhargavRao Ok, should I create a new question or leave this for now?

Comment: @Scooby Create a new question if *you have a new question*. That is simple as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost literally translate this Matlab code

```
for i = N:-1:2
    z = randn(M/2,1);
    w = t(i)*w/t(i+1) + sigma*sqrt(dt*t(i)/t(i+1))*[z;-z];
end
```

to Eigen (assuming everything outside the loop works):

```
MatrixXd zz(M,1); // allocate space for [z; -z] only once
for(int i=N; i>=2; --i){
    zz.topRows(M/2) = generateGaussianNoise(M/2,1);
    zz.bottomRows(M/2) = -zz.topRows(M/2);

    w = t(i-1)*w/t(i) + sigma*std::sqrt(dt*t(i-1)/t(i))*zz;
}
```

Essentially, the only difference is that Matlab starts indexing at 1 and Eigen starts at 0.

Also concatenating `[z;-z]` is not possible "inlined" in Eigen, but I'm wondering why you do the same calculations for `z` and `-z` anyway ...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the sytax I need to use. I am not sure why the "matlab code does the [z;-z] since it does not seem to be clarified in the actual algorithm if I find out ill let you know

Comment: Trying what you suggested I am getting an error when I call the sqrt function it states:

Comment: Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
double sqrt(double)
float sqrt(float)
long double sqrt(long double)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type sqrt(#0)
const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sqrt_op<#0::Scalar>,const #0> sqrt(const Eigen::ArrayBase<#0> &)
float sqrt(float)
long double sqrt(long double)
std::complex<#0> sqrt(const std::complex<#0> &)
__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<74 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #074 0 __value 14 std::__is_integer 1 #0,double>::__type

Comment: Try `std::sqrt` and if that does not work, `std::sqrt<double>` instead of `sqrt`.

Comment: I am sorry I am really a novice in C++ so I do not really understand the syntax your suggesting to use. Could you maybe just edit your answer or tell me how to do what you suggest.

Comment: the std::sqrt() does not work I do you implement the other one you suggested

Comment: `w.exp()` is not correct either, but that is an independent question, so I won't answer it here.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786662/](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33786662/).

Answer (score 1):

The following line does not make sense:

```
zz(i) = generateMatrix(z);
```

`zz(i)` is a `double&` whereas `generateMatrix` returns a `MatrixXd`. Same for `w(i)`.

Comment: I see, do you know how I would fix that? I have to do a sort of backward recursion for the algorithm so I am not sure what to do.